# Can't import a package in Spyder while can import in python terminal

Tags: python, path, spyder

When I use the Python terminal, there is no import problems at all. But when I try to import, for example, keras or try to use scipy.misc.imsave() Spyder says `ModuleNotFound` and `AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'imsave'` respectively. Below is the sys.path of python terminal and Spyder.I would appreciate any fix for this problem.

Python 3.6.3 terminal

```
    ['', 
'C:\\Users\\kaany\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python36.zip',
    'C:\\Users\\kaany\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Users\\kaany\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib',
    'C:\\Users\\kaany\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36', 
    'C:\\Users\\kaany\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages', 
    'C:\\Users\\kaany\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\mudicom-0.1.2-py3.6.egg']
```

Spyder

```
['',
 'C:\\Users\\kaany\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\kaany\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\kaany\\Anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\kaany\\Anaconda3',
 'C:\\Users\\kaany\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\kaany\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Babel-2.5.0-py3.6.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\kaany\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Mako-1.0.7-py3.6.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\kaany\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\kaany\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\kaany\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\kaany\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\kaany\\.ipython']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/flatironinstitute/CaImAn/wiki/Setting-up-Python-and-getting-to-know-Spyder

Is your pythonPath set up correctly?